# Azure list Azure Database for PostgreSQL servers in Resource group using Azure Java SDK

Tags: java, postgresql, azure, sdk, azure-java-sdk

What is the best and correct way to list Azure Database for PostgreSQL servers present in my Resource Group using Azure Java SDK?
Currently, we have deployments that happen using ARM templates and once the resources have been deployed we want to be able to get the information about those resources from Azure itself.
I have tried doing in the following way:

```
PagedList<SqlServer> azureSqlServers = azure1.sqlServers().listByResourceGroup("resourceGrpName");
//PagedList<SqlServer> azureSqlServers = azure1.sqlServers().list();
for(SqlServer azureSqlServer : azureSqlServers) {
    System.out.println(azureSqlServer.fullyQualifiedDomainName());
}
System.out.println(azureSqlServers.size());
```

But the list size returned is `0`.

However, for virtual machines, I am able to get the information in the following way:

```
PagedList<VirtualMachine> vms = azure1.virtualMachines().listByResourceGroup("resourceGrpName");
for (VirtualMachine vm : vms) {
    System.out.println(vm.name());
    System.out.println(vm.powerState());
    System.out.println(vm.size());
    System.out.println(vm.tags());
}
```

So, what is the right way of getting the information about the `Azure Database for PostgreSQL` using Azure Java SDK?

P.S.
Once I get the information regarding Azure Database for PostgreSQL, I would need similar information about the `Azure Database for MySQL Servers`.

Edit: I have seen this question which was asked 2 years back and would like to know if Azure added Support for Azure Database for PostgreSQL/MySQL servers or not.
[Azure Java SDK for MySQL/PostgreSQL databases?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45932470/azure-java-sdk-for-mysql-postgresql-databases)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to my test, we can use java sdk `azure-mgmt-resources` to implement your need. For example

1. Create a service principal

```
az login
# it will create a service pricipal and assign a contributor rolen to the sp
az ad sp create-for-rbac -n "MyApp"  --scope "/subscriptions/<subscription id>" --sdk-auth
```

[image]

2. code

```
        String tenantId = "<the tenantId you copy >";
        String clientId = "<the clientId you copy>";
        String clientSecret= "<the clientSecre you copy>";
        String subscriptionId = "<the subscription id you copy>";
       ApplicationTokenCredentials creds = new 
          ApplicationTokenCredentials(clientId,domain,secret,AzureEnvironment.AZURE);
            RestClient restClient =new RestClient.Builder()
                                   .withBaseUrl(AzureEnvironment.AZURE, AzureEnvironment.Endpoint.RESOURCE_MANAGER)
                                   .withSerializerAdapter(new AzureJacksonAdapter())
                                   .withReadTimeout(150, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                                   .withLogLevel(LogLevel.BODY)
                                   .withResponseBuilderFactory(new AzureResponseBuilder.Factory())
                                   .withCredentials(creds)
                                   .build();


            ResourceManager resourceClient= ResourceManager.authenticate(restClient).withSubscription(subscriptionId);
            ResourceManagementClientImpl  client=  resourceClient.inner();

            String filter="resourceType eq 'Microsoft.DBforPostgreSQL/servers'"; //The filter to apply on the operation
            String expand=null;//The $expand query parameter. You can expand createdTime and changedTime.For example, to expand both properties, use $expand=changedTime,createdTime
            Integer top =null;// The number of results to return. If null is passed, returns all resource groups.
            PagedList<GenericResourceInner> results= client.resources().list(filter, null,top);
            while (true) {
                for (GenericResourceInner resource : results.currentPage().items()) {

                    System.out.println(resource.id());
                    System.out.println(resource.name());
                    System.out.println(resource.type());
                    System.out.println(resource.location());
                    System.out.println(resource.sku().name());
                    System.out.println("------------------------------");
                }
                if (results.hasNextPage()) {
                    results.loadNextPage();
                } else {
                    break;
                }
            }
```

[image]

Besides, you also can use Azure REST API to implement your need. For more details, please refer to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/resources/resources

Comment: Thanks @Jim Xu, this is helpful. I implemented in a somewhat similar manner after going through the `Azure` class from `package com.microsoft.azure.management;` I want to upvote your answer but votes cast by user less 15 points are just recorded but not shown publicly. I will be posting my method below and you can provide more inputs on it if you like.

Answer (score 1):

So, I kind of implemented it in the following way and it can be treated as an alternative way...
Looking at the Azure SDK for java repo on Github (https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-java/tree/master/sdk/postgresql), looks like they have it in beta so I searched for the pom in mvnrepository. I imported the following pom in my project (azure-mgmt-postgresql is still in beta):

```
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.microsoft.azure.postgresql.v2017_12_01/azure-mgmt-postgresql -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.microsoft.azure.postgresql.v2017_12_01</groupId>
    <artifactId>azure-mgmt-postgresql</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0-beta-5</version>
</dependency>
```

In the code, Following is the gist of how I did it:
I already have a service principal created and have its information with me.
But, anyone trying this will require `clientId`, `tenantId`, `clientSecret`, and `subscriptionId` with them, the way @Jim Xu explained.

```
// create the credentials object
ApplicationTokenCredentials credentials = new ApplicationTokenCredentials(clientId, tenantId, clientSecret, AzureEnvironment.AZURE);

// build a rest client object configured with the credentials created above
RestClient restClient = new RestClient.Builder()
        .withBaseUrl(credentials.environment(), AzureEnvironment.Endpoint.RESOURCE_MANAGER)
        .withCredentials(credentials)
        .withSerializerAdapter(new AzureJacksonAdapter())
        .withResponseBuilderFactory(new AzureResponseBuilder.Factory())
        .withInterceptor(new ProviderRegistrationInterceptor(credentials))
        .withInterceptor(new ResourceManagerThrottlingInterceptor())
        .build();

// use the PostgreSQLManager
PostgreSQLManager psqlManager = PostgreSQLManager.authenticate(restClient, subscriptionId);
PagedList<Server> azurePsqlServers = psqlManager.servers().listByResourceGroup(resourceGrpName);
for(Server azurePsqlServer : azurePsqlServers) {
    System.out.println(azurePsqlServer.fullyQualifiedDomainName());
    System.out.println(azurePsqlServer.userVisibleState().toString());
    System.out.println(azurePsqlServer.sku().name());    
}
```

Note: `Server` class refers to `com.microsoft.azure.management.postgresql.v2017_12_01.Server`

Also, if you take a look at the `Azure` class, you will notice this is how they do it internally.

For reference, you can use `SqlServerManager sqlServerManager` in the `Azure` class and look at how they have used it and created an authenticated manager in case you want to use some services that are still in `preview` or `beta`.